# regex that shouldn't work works

Tags: python, regex

im starting to learn regex and i tried to make a simple regex that doesn't make sense to match but it matched any way
i tried in python

```
import re


pattern = r'[a-z]+[a-z]'



print re.findall(pattern,"adasdasad");
```

it returned ['adasdasad']
where it shouldn't have worked because [a-z]+ should have consumed the whole string and the rest ([a-z]) won't find any thing to conusme why it evaluates ????

Comment: No, because `+` is not a *possessive* quantifier.

Comment: You can test your regex here - https://regex101.com/

Comment: `+` doesn't consume the whole string, it consumes as much as possible. That's a huge difference.

Answer (score 5):

The `+` is not a possessive quantifier and allows backtracking into the quantified subpattern.

The `[a-z]+` matches `adasdasa` and `[a-z]` matches `d`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/fG5rS2/1).

[image]

BTW, if you used `[a-z]++[a-z]` with PCRE (a pattern with a possessive quantifier `++`), it would never match anything as it would require to match 1 or more letters and then another letter that would be already consumed with the first subpattern. So, that is the same as `(?!)` pattern.

Comment: thank you can you give more info about a reference to learn more about these things

Comment: What exact topic are you interested in? In general, I can suggest doing all lessons at [regexone.com](http://regexone.com/), reading through [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info), [regex SO tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) (with many other links to great online resources), and the community SO post called [What does the regex mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean). A [rexegg.com](http://rexegg.com) is also a great site.